# Unicode character(s) that look like iOS7 left-pointing navigation chevron

Tags: ios, ios7, unicode, uinavigationbar

What are the Unicode characters that most closely approximate the size (as large or larger than a capital letter) and shape of the iOS7+ backwards-pointing Navigation Bar chevron?

[image]

I'm looking for a hacky way to use unicode characters to simulate the "navigate back" chevron for a view that doesn't normally have "go back" navigation.

A regular < (less-than sign)  is not good  because it's not tall enough and not vertically centered. A ‹ (European left quote) is more vertically centered but it's also not tall enough. ᐸ (U+1438) is the best I've found so far because it's as tall as a capital letter, but its angle is 52° while the iOS arrow is 90°, so it looks different and takes up a lot of extra horizontal real estate.

Are there any other better options for full-height chevrons that have a less acute angle than ᐸ (U+1438) ?

It doesn't have to be perfect, just close enough to buy us time until our team can implement a custom view using real images.

Comment: I'm not going to have a good answer either way, probably, but is this an attributed text field? Can the chevron be in a different font?

Comment: Do you need to use a unicode character, or can you use an image?

Comment: need a unicode character

Comment: @Tommy - unfortunately we're stuck with one font today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these:

1. Left pointing angle bracket U+2329 `〈 Home`
2. Vertical Kana Repeat Mark U+3031 `〱Home`

Comment: The second one isn't supported by the Helvetica Neue that iOS supports for that spot. I used the first; it's meh, but better than nothing for now. FWIW, here's the actual formulation: NSLocalizedString(@"\U00002329 Back", nil)

Comment: Very useful. CSS auto correction throws out the Vertical Kana though. Thanks for sharing!